# Copy files using bash

Tags: bash

I have two work dirs each of which is consisted of several folders (the name of those folders are equal between both dirs) .

```
from=/home/cmoon/OR5P3_4nax
to=/home/cmoon/total_decomp
```

Because names of each folders in `$from` correspond to those folders in `$to` I need to copy some file (`md.in`) from one folder to another using:

```
for sim in ${from}/OR5P3_* ; do
 if [[ -d $sim ]]; then
   title=$(basename "$sim")
   pushd $sim
   cp md.nc ${to}/${title}/md3.nc
   popd
 fi
done
```

Here I use `${title}` to be sure that `md.nc` will be copied from each initial folder in dir1 to the folder with the exactly same name in the dir2:

```
e.g  /${from}/lala1 -> /${to}/lala1
e.g  /${from}/lala2 -> /${to}/lala2
e.g  /${from}/lala10 -> /${to}/lala10
```

*Is this script correct ?*

How to add some printing message to the script to see from what exactly (I guess using PWD) folder to.

Comment: use `cp -v` for verbose output.

Answer (score 0):

If the directory `${to}/${title}` does not exist, the copy will fail. Make sure it exists first:

```
mkdir -p "$to/$title"          # use `-p` to avoid error if it already exists
cp md.nc "$to/$title/md3.nc"
```

Remember to quote your `"$vars"` -- braces are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Has @arco444 suggest you can you `cp -v`, `cp` will then output `from -> to`.

Otherwise you can add in the loop:

```
 echo "coping in folder: $to/$title"
```